# Populating datatable from Form data

Tags: jquery, html, forms, datatable

I am looking to populate a data table from the data input into the form but not having any joy...

When I press submit it clears the form and returns to top of screen but does not populate the table

A scaled-down version of the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  

    var t = $('#job-table').DataTable();
    var counter = 1;

    $('#submit').on('click', function() {
  var text1 = $(".add-company").val();
     var text2 = $(".add-contact").val();
     var text3 = $(".add-from").val();
     var text4 = $(".add-to").val();
     var text5 = $(".add-driver").val();
     var text6 = $(".add-income").val();
     var text7 = $(".add-payment").val();
     t.row.add([
      text1,
      text2,
      text3,
      text4,
      text5,
      text6,
      text7
  ]).draw(false);

  counter++;
    });

    // Automatically add a first row of data
    $('#submit').click();
});
```

The jQuery, as far as I can tell is correct so unsure what is stopping the table from populating.

Any help would be amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. change the type submit to button for your submit button
2. prevent default action (form submission): [e.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

Moreover, I would suggest to change how to trigger events in jQuery:

from: `$('#submit').click();`

to: `$('#submit').trigger('click');`

The snippet:

```js
var t = $('#job-table').DataTable();
var counter = 1;

$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text1 = $(".add-company").val();
    var text2 = $(".add-contact").val();
    var text3 = $(".add-from").val();
    var text4 = $(".add-to").val();
    var text5 = $(".add-driver").val();
    var text6 = $(".add-income").val();
    var text7 = $(".add-payment").val();
    t.row.add([
        text1,
        text2,
        text3,
        text4,
        text5,
        text6,
        text7,
            0,
            0
    ]).draw(false);

    counter++;
});

// Automatically add a first row of data
$('#submit').trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div class="tile" id="tile-1">
    <div class="addjob tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <h2>Add info</h2>
        <form name="dataform" method="post">
                <span>
            <p>Date:</p>
            <input class="add-date" type="date" placeholder="Placeholder Text">
        </span>
        <span>
            <p>Customer/Company Name:</p>
            <input class="add-company" type="select" placeholder="Company-name Ltd" value="1">
        </span>
            <span>
                <p>Contact Name:</p>
                <input class="add-contact" type="text" placeholder="John Doe"  value="2">
            </span>
            <span>
                <p>From:</p>
                <input class="add-from" type="text" placeholder="Address 1"  value="3">
            </span>
            <span>
                <p>To:</p>
                <input class="add-to" type="text" placeholder="Address 2" value="4">
            </span>
            <span>
                <p>subbie Name:</p>
                <input class="add-driver" type="select" placeholder="Driver Name (Company)" value="5">
            </span>
            <span>
                <p>Income (£):</p>
                <input class="add-income" type="text" placeholder="£120" value="6">
            </span>
            <span>
                <p>subbie Payment (£):</p>
                <input class="add-payment" type="text" placeholder="£100" value="7">
            </span>
            <span>
                <p>Driver Vat registered?</p>
                <input class="add-payment" type="text" placeholder="Yes/No" value="8">
            </span>
            <span>
                <button id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
            </span>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="viewalljob">
        <h2>Job</h2>
        <table id="job-table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Company Name</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th>subbie</th>
                <th>Income (£)</th>
                <th>subbiePayment (£)</th>
                <th>Profit (£)</th>
                <th>Markup (%)</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can see that the code works fine here. but it does not seem to work whe I run it love. I will keep trying. There is a lot more to my code, this was only a small clip. but I will work on it a bit more

Comment: So the code appears to be right, just not accepted by the environment in which it is running? I used the code in codepen and it doesn't work there either but does on here for some reason... have you any ideas of a potential fix? Sorry, im quite inexperienced in all this, im studying toward my degree but it is essentially a hobby rather than a profession

Comment: Ive not saved it, I just use it to try out code, I don't even have an account. Ill set one up and add the link

Comment: But if you copy and paste the code you gave in your answer into codepen, you should get the same result as me

Comment: Im now confused as to how your code worked and when I copy and paste it into my code it isnt working. Ill need to debug my code a bit deeper. thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it